# Mapstruct : how to use MappingControl tu disable some automapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

So

i have a class

```
public class Customer {

    private String magicid;
    private String name;


}

public class CustomerDto {

    public String id;
    public String customerName;
}
```

and a mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CustomerMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "customerName", target = "name")
    @Mapping(target= magicId, expression="java(getMagicId(customerDto.getId()))")
    Customer toCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto);

public String getMagicId(String id)
...
return magicId
```

the thing is, mapstruct see the string to string mapper and use it for the mapping of customerName

what can i do to prevent that?

I have seen that there is a MappingControl option that I can use in the @Mapper annotation but i can't figure out how to use it. does someone have an exemple? is it the only way?

note : I am fairly new to java and I really have a hard time understanding *how* an annotation works/can be parametered

Answer (score 1):

The MappingControl cannot be used in this situation.

What you are looking for is to mark the `getMagicId` method to be special, i.e. qualify it.

You can do it by using [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

e.g.

```java
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CustomerMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "customerName", target = "name")
    @Mapping(target = "magicId", source = ="id", qualifiedByName = "magicId")
    Customer toCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto);

    @Named("magicId")
    default public String getMagicId(String id)
        ...
        return magicId
    }
}
```

Note how using qualifiers allows you to avoid the use of the expression.